# Filtering Onedrive items by lastModifiedDatetime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to filter OneDrive items from within the Microsoft Graph endpoint, by lastModifiedDatetime property.

Something like that :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/special/photos/children?$top=3&$orderBy=lastModifiedDatetime
```

It doesn't work.
The error returned is :

> "message": "The request is not supported by the system."

But according to the documentation ( https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/optional-query-parameters.htm#optional-odata-query-parameters )

> **oderby** : Comma-separated list of properties that are used to sort the order of items in the response collection. Works for name, size, and lastModifiedDateTime fields.

By the way, I tried to sort with the name property and it actually works as expected :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/special/photos/children?$top=3&$orderBy=lastModifiedDatetime
```

Can you confirm than sorting by **lastModifiedDateTime** is not permitted with the graph api endpoint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering by lastModifiedDateTime is not supported for OneDrive for Business. It is supported for OneDrive Personal. The limitation is not specific to the Microsoft Graph endpoint. There is a note about it in the referenced  documentation page.

Comment: Thx Marek. I didn't find the note about this, can you point me where it is, please ?

Comment: It's in the "Sorting collections" section:
"Note that in OneDrive for Business, the orderby query string only works with name and url."