# Sort file list by lastModifiedDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to sort a file list by lastModifiedDateTime property of the fileSystemInfo property, like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/9e8fd8af-b7fe-4cfe-9b16-81e8358f3bec/drive/root/children?$orderby=fileSystemInfo/lastModifiedDateTime%20desc
```

I get an 'notSupported' error message from API
Is this supported, or is the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i can repro the issue as well. Sounds like filtering by lastModifiedDateTime is not supported for OneDrive for Business. It is supported for OneDrive Personal. The limitation is not specific to the Microsoft Graph endpoint. There is a note about it in the referenced documentation page.

Please refer the older thread - [Filtering Onedrive items by lastModifiedDatetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493030/filtering-onedrive-items-by-lastmodifieddatetime)