# Date filter on One Drive Graph API not working

Tags: onedrive

I have following date filter query on one drive with greater than operator.

```
lastModifiedDateTime gt 2020-08-29T10:48:41.000Z


https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='test')?filter=lastModifiedDateTime%20gt%202020-08-29T10%3A48%3A41.000Z
```

But it always returns empty result. I have following file detail displaying on one drive.

```
Type: SRT File
Modified: 8/29/2020 04:40 PM
Added: by me
Date created: 8/29/2020 04:39 PM
Path: My file > stest
Size: 101 KB
```

Just additional info. I am able to access all files using following url.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Onedrive items by lastModifiedDatetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493030/filtering-onedrive-items-by-lastmodifieddatetime)